# Putting logic in ViewModel get'ers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

What do you think about putting Get-logic in the getters of a ViewModel? Something like:

```
public class DummyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private DummyObject myObject;

    public DummyObject MyObject
    {
        get
        {
            if (MyObject == null)
            {
                DummyRepository repo = new DummyRepository();
                myObject = repo.Get(Id);
            }
            return myObject;
        }
    }

}
```

Is this bad practice, or totally fine? I find my controllers getting really bloated by doing all the get-logic there, but I'm really torn as to where I should put it...

My reason for doing it this way, is that I can pass the ViewModel to different types of view, and only the neccessary DB-lookup will be performed based on what property is requested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with putting logic in getters in VMs - the role of a VM is to present data to a view, and it should be as ready to "view" as possible (the View should not be having to do too much (if any) work to shape the data before showing it).

As an example, I use properties called `GetAvailableClients` in my VM, and that will be one of the properties that the View binds to. The job of that particular getter is to filter data  - IOW present a reduced set of data selected from a complete list (which is also held in the VM), that data will usually be filtered using LINQ, which means I have placed some custom logic in the getter.

What I am not a fan of though is the rest of your approach, where if the property hasn't been filled it goes off to the repository and gets the data itself. To me that is a no-no, the property is totally violating the principle of [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) by making the property responsible for too much. Not to mention that is not a good practice to follow once you start binding that property to the UI - suddenly your app will start hanging when the user performs an action because your property getter has been triggered and it has decided to make a call to the database or a webservice, and to make it worse that call has been done on the UI thread.... it just gets ugly.

Comment: Excellent response! So what you think is that I could have a private method GetDummyObjects(), and then use my getters to do a
 return GetDummyObjects().Where(some lambda-expression)

?
Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yep, that is similar to what i would do, but i would split it up further. The *GetDummyObjects()* call would be done as part of the constructor or load of the VM, or done by a supervising controller which then passes in the results. The *Where(lambda)* would be in the getter.

Comment: Just to elaborate a little further, one reason for having the *Where(lambda)* in the getter is because your main list might be a homogenous list of objects - it might be a list of orders that also contains some client info. Instead of making several calls to a repository (which could be an expensive task timewise), you can show a list of clients in the View simply by filtering/selecting the info from the list of orders that the VM has. This still fits within the mandateof the VM - it presents data to the View.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is generic, but I'll answer as best as I can.

I don't like these things:

1) Testability. Your property is creating the repository, how are you going to mock up your repository and test this?

2) Lazy loading. Lazy loading is a potential performance hit and the viewmodel should not be doing it. What happens if you bind your viewmodel to a grid with hundreds of entries?

3) Exposing Id. Your Id property (which I am assuming is the primary key value of the entity) has a setter. Are you going to present this Id in the view? If not, get rid of it, if so, remove the setter. The setter implies that the view must perform some sort of biz functionality to look up the correct value and this breaks SoC.

Comment: This is the approach I want to go for, keeping my ViewModels simple and "dumb".. So in your approach you'd do all the data-retrieving in the controller, fill the model and return it to the view? (I would guess this is the 'correct' way to do it)

Comment: I don't have a controller (but that's another discussion). My ViewModel would have a DataSource property refering to your DummyObject so that the viewmodel is repository ignorant. If this ViewModel is used by another ViewModel in a master/detail relationship the "master" ViewModel would have a provider/repository ref used to initialize the detail ViewModel datasource. So "dumbness" depends on which level you operate on, but remember to maintain SOLID principles at any level :-)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I do not include any logic in my view models - they are pretty much dumb DTOs.  I certainly wouldn't make a VM responsible for it's own loading via a repository.