# I'm injecting my Service into my controller. Should I inject my Service into my ViewModel instead?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control, design-patterns

So, I've been building a brand new website to replace our current classic asp site.  I set up a base project and added in all the different technologies I would be using.

Ninject
Automapper
PagedList
EF 4.0

So far I have a working prototype of the website.  It pulls data from the database, and displays in on my page.  I think I am not following a pattern correctly.  Because my controller action looks strange.  I'm beginning to think I need to change my injection to inject my service into my viewmodel?  Is it common to insert a service into a ViewModel?

### ViewModel

```
 public class ParcelDetailViewModel
    {
        public Property Property { get; set; }
        public int CurrentYear { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<AltOwnership> AltOwnership { get; set; }
        public Ownership Ownership { get; set; }
        public TotalValues TotalValues { get; set; }
        public SiteAddressViewModel SiteAddress { get; set; }
        public Value CurrentValues { get; set; }

        public Transfer LatestTransfer { get; set; }
        public LegalDescription LegalDescription { get; set; }

    }
```

### Controller

```
public class PropertyController : Controller
{
    ICamaService _service = null;

    [Inject]
    public PropertyController(ICamaService  service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    //TODO: ADD ACTIONS

    public ViewResult List(int? page, int? size = 100)
    {
        var result = _service.GetProperties(page,size);
        IList<ParcelDetailViewModel> ViewModel;
        ViewModel = new List<ParcelDetailViewModel>();
        Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Models.Property>, IEnumerable<ParcelDetailViewModel>>(result, ViewModel);
        return View(ViewModel.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, size ?? 100));

    }


    public ViewResult Details(string id)
    {
        var property = _service.GetProperty(id);
        var acct = property.AccountNumber;
        var AltOwners = _service.GetAltOwners(id);
        var LegalDescription = _service.GetLegalDescription(id);
        var Legals = _service.GetLegals(id).FirstOrDefault();
        var Ownership = _service.GetOwnership((decimal)property.OwnerLookup);
        var Values = _service.GetValues(acct);
        var TotalValues = _service.GetTotalValues(acct);
        var Location = _service.GetLocation(property.LocationLookup);

        ParcelDetailViewModel ViewModel = new ParcelDetailViewModel();
        SiteAddressViewModel SitusAddress = new SiteAddressViewModel();

        ViewModel.SiteAddress = SitusAddress;

        Mapper.Map<Models.Property, ParcelDetailViewModel>(property, ViewModel);
        Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AltOwnership>, ParcelDetailViewModel>(AltOwners, ViewModel);
        Mapper.Map<Ownership, ParcelDetailViewModel>(Ownership, ViewModel);
        Mapper.Map<TotalValues, ParcelDetailViewModel>(TotalValues, ViewModel);

        Mapper.Map(Location, SitusAddress);
        Mapper.Map(property, SitusAddress);


        return View(ViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: What is the pattern are you using? ViewModel is MVVM, Cntroler is from MVC? SO are you using both?

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe that is part of my problem.  My Models are so unlike my views I need something to bring the two closer together.  I've seen other web applications using viewModels.

Comment: This is an example using controllers and ViewModels. I think. http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part6.htm

Comment: Controllers and view models together is not unusual. The server is using MVC, but the M is actually a VM since there is another M in the database or domain layer.

Comment: @Domenic thank you for clarifying. That was my understanding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Injecting services into controllers is perfectly correct.

On the other hand, injecting any services into view models would be against the idea of view models - classes which hold data and no actions. What would you do with a service inside a view model?

Comment: The database Models are so far removed from the way the data needs to be displayed on the View. Some properties are from 3 or 4 fields in several tables, that become 1 field on the view.

Comment: That's correct. And it's still the controller responsible for creating such model.

Comment: So in my controller I could have (for example) a line that populates a property in my ViewModel from two different services  , `ViewModel.Name = _service.FirstName + _service2.LastName`

Comment: It smells like a potential bottleneck but yes, the responsibility is in the controller.

Comment: If the construction of the ViewModel's data is non-trivial, you might want to extract the logic into its own class that the controller can delegate to, but you still would not put it into the ViewModel itself.

Comment: I'm not agree that ViewModels just holds a data, this is accordingly to which pattern? In MVVM ViewModel is aware of business logic and has access to many services, encapsulates different commands and so on. Perhaps you mean `Model`?

Comment: @sil. We are talking about MVC. MVC is NOT the MVVM. Both MVC and MVVM use the term 'view model' but the idea is slightly different. I think you lack the experience with ASP.NET MVC and you try to look through the lens of your knowledge of MVVM.

Comment: I do agree with you about injecting into the controller and personally my viewmodels don't contain logic, _however_ a ViewModel can indeed have logic (yes in MVC) that is specific to the view. For example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712394/putting-logic-in-viewmodel-geters    Some prefer to contain this logic elsewhere, but as long as theres no persistent code required in it, it can be done.